# Transformation of random variables in Generative Adversarial Nets

Tags: probability, calculus

Let $x$ and $z$ be real-valued random vectors, where $x = g(z)$, and $g$ is an invertible, continuous and differentiable transformation of $z$. Then $p_z(z) = p_x(g(z)) \lvert det(\frac{\partial g(z)}{\partial z})\rvert $. However, the equation 3 of Proposition 1 in [Generative Adversarial Nets](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.2661.pdf) seems to suggest $p_z(z)dz = p_x(x)dx$, without the determinant. I wonder how to derive this equality.

**EDIT**:
Thanks to Chill2Macht's comment, I read and watched the resources regarding change of variables. However, I am still not sure where 'det' went in $p_z(z)dz = p_x(x)dx$. For example, let $x = \mu + \sigma z$, where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are constants. Then $\frac{\partial x}{\partial z} = \sigma$, and $p(x)dx = \sigma p(g(z)) dz$. Using their derivation, 
$\sigma$ should not be present.

Comment: This is just change of variables http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChangeofVariablesTheorem.html This is purely a calculus issue. Here are two videos where a professor at MIT explains how it's done: (1) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lCKxeRiBdjQ  (2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G534bz09B4A  Are you sure that you have the basic mathematical prerequisites to be attempting to learn about this topic?

Comment: I appreciate your comment on my edit, thx.

Comment: The determinant of a 1 by 1 matrix (i.e. a scalar) is just the scalar itself. So using their formulation, $\sigma$ would be present. (I.e. $\sigma = \det(\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}) = \frac{\partial x}{\partial z}$ since you are assuming everything is one-dimensional)

Comment: Maybe this source will be more useful, since it explains the one-dimensional case in detail before moving on to the general case: https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring11/sta114/lec/114mvnorm.pdf  This one doesn't explain the multi-dimensional case, but explains the one-dimensional case in even more detail: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/157

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: $p_z(g^{-1}(x))$ is not a probability density function of $x$ because it doesn't integrate to 1. $p_z(g^{-1}(x))\lvert det(\frac{\partial(g^{-1}(x))}{\partial x})\rvert$ is the probability density function of $x$, and I think in the GAN paper, the $p_g(x)$ represents this expression.